# How can I use 'es6-promise' polyfill

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

My TypeScript project does not use 'npm', how can I use  'es6-promise' polyfill without relying on `npm install es6-promise`? I just compile using 'tsc'.

From https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/master/dist/es6-promise.js, how can I include that in my Typescript as a `type definition`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*lib* compiler option](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib):

> with --lib you can specify a list of built-in API declaration groups that you can chose to include in your project. For instance, if you expect your runtime to have support for Map, Set and Promise (e.g. most evergreen browsers today), just include --lib es2015.collection,es2015.promise.

Or in *tsconfig.json*, for example:

```
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015.promise", "es5"]
```

Full list of available compiler options [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).